# Duration with daylight saving

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, dst, duration

I have an object `Shift`, with two fields: `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` as `DateTime` from Joda-Time.

And my shift includes Daylight Saving UK change. It starts on `25/03/2017 13:00` and ends on `26/03/2017 02:00` (basically should end on `26/03/2017 01:00`, but this date does not exists, and `endDate` is shifted +1 hour). According to this [site](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london):

> When local standard time was about to reach
>   Sunday, 26 March 2017, 01:00:00 clocks were turned forward 1 hour to 
>   Sunday, 26 March 2017, 02:00:00 local daylight time instead.

Now if I want to track the number of hours worked by a employee
 `new Duration(startDateTime, endDateTime).toStandardHours().getHours()` will give me 13 hours.

How can I detect if Daylight Saving starts or ends on my shift duration using Joda-Time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone` class. It has information about DST changes for all timezones in the world, so you don't need to detect the DST change: if you correctly inform which timezone you're using, the API does the job for you.

As you're working with UK timezone, you can use directly the `Europe/London` timezone - these names in the format `Continent/City` comes from the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), and it's used by Joda-Time, Java and many other APIs. You can get a list of all timezones by calling `DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

When you use a `DateTimeZone`, it already contains all the DST shifts during history, so the API does all the math for you. You just need to create your `DateTime` instances at this timezone:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

// London timezone - it contains all info about DST shifts
DateTimeZone london = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");

// Start on 25/03/2017 13:00
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 3, 25, 13, 0, london);
// ends on 26/03/2017 02:00
DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 3, 26, 2, 0, london);

// get the difference between start and end
Duration duration = new Duration(start, end);
System.out.println(duration.getStandardHours()); // 12
```

The output will be `12` (the API uses the information of the `DateTime`'s timezones to calculate the difference, including DST shifts).

You can also use:

```
duration.toStandardHours().getHours()
```

Or the class `org.joda.time.Hours`:

```
Hours.hoursBetween(start, end).getHours()
```

All of them return `12`, and they're all equivalent.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time it's being discontinued and replaced by the new APIs, so if you're considering a migration, you can start using the new Date/Time API, but if you have a big codebase using Joda or don't want to migrate it now, you can desconsider the rest of the answer.

Anyway, even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). I'm not sure if it's already available to all Android versions (but see the alternative below).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's a way to use it, with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The new API also uses IANA timezones names and contains the same historical information about the DST shifts (to get a list of all timezones: `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`). The code is very similar, and there's also more than one way to get the difference:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

// London timezone
ZoneId london = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

// Start on 25/03/2017 13:00
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 3, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0, london);
// ends on 26/03/2017 02:00
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 3, 26, 2, 0, 0, 0, london);

// get the difference in hours
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start, end)); // 12

// get the duration in hours
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
System.out.println(duration.toHours()); // 12

// using until() method
System.out.println(start.until(end, ChronoUnit.HOURS)); // 12
```

All the three methods above (`ChronoUnit.HOURS.between()`, `duration.toHours()` and `start.until()`) return `12`. According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-), `between` and `until` are equivalent, [as the first just internally calls the second](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.java#l270). Using a `Duration` is also equivalent, as it uses the nanoseconds between them and convert it to hours.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use TimeZone ID e.g., "Europe/London"
2. Convert start and end time into GMT
3. Now find the duration from GMT start and end times

Daylight is automatically handled when u use TimeZone IDs.